# Why "directory-expression" is not creating dynamic folder ddMMyyyy using regex on linux server?

Tags: regex, linux, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring jms integration to consume mq message and file integration outbound-channel-adapter move error mq message (if any) to dynamic folder error/filtered/ddMMyyyy using "directory-expression" and regex.

mqMsgFeedChannel checks if mq message is subject to filter or not? if yes then it should be move msg to today's date 04102018 (ddMMyyyy) folder where `myproject.consumer.filter.output.dir=/our_nas_drive/our_project/data/our_env/error/filtered`.

```
<int:filter id="mqMessageFilter" expression="${myproject.consumer.filter.expression:true}" input-channel="mqMsgFeedChannel" output-channel="mqMsgProcessChannel" discard-channel="filterFileOutputChannel" throw-exception-on-rejection="false"/>
```

I can see mq depth is increased by 1 when a message is published and reduced to 0 once consume, but configuration is not creating dynamic directory. Also checked by creating directory manually even now its not moving error message file to static 04102018 folder.

I checked if its permission issue, by "directory" attribute for static folder without regex and I can confirm that its not a permission issue.

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filterFileOutput" channel="filterFileOutputChannel" auto-create-directory="true" directory-expression="'${myproject.consumer.filter.output.dir}'+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('ddMMyyyy').format(new java.util.Date())" delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Looks like this regular expression works well in windows but not on Linux once deployed on server.

Please advice, thank you in advance

Tom